# Closing a livesearch box by clicking off it

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

I think the best example is on this link:

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_livesearch.asp

If you type a keyword in the example search field, the suggestions drop down. I have replicated this code but would like to add a small change. When you the suggestions drop down I would like to be able to click anywhere other then the list on the webpage to close/hide the suggestion list again. Similar to facebook search, where clicking off the list, closes it.

I have used the same javascript as shown in the above link, but what would I need to add?

A click handler attached to the body element?

Answer (score 1):

Events have [capturing/bubbling](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html) phases. You want to capture the bubbled `click` on the body:

```
$(document.body).on('click', function() { $('#live_search_id').hide(); });
```

Then, cancel the bubble `event.preventDefault()` when the live search area is clicked:

```
$('#live_search_id').on('click', function(e){
    /* ... applicable logic - if any ... */
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Thank you Xander, will try that tonight!

Comment: Wont this also fire if you click the #live_search_id though?

Answer (score 0):

```
$.on('click', document.body, function() { 
    // Check if this is not #live_search_id or a child
    if ( $(this) != ($'#live_search_id') && $(this).parents('#live_search_id').length == 0) {
        $('#live_search_id').hide(); 
    }
});
```